# Finding intersections of most number of intervals

Tags: algorithm, intervals

I am looking for a data structure that can perform following operations:

- Insert and delete intervals.
- At any time, return the intersections [x;y] of most current intervals.

For example, if current intervals are [1,5], [3,6], [2,7] and [8,9] then the returned intersection is [3,5] with 3 overlapped intervals. But if [3,6] is deleted and [0,4] is inserted, the answer is [2,4].

Note that, starting and ending points of intervals can be any number other than integers.

Thanks,

Comment: Have a look at [interval trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and [segment trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree)

Comment: @BasSwinckels: Yes, I'm trying but not successfully yet.

Comment: @user2210078 Do you want an algorithm that returns no intersection for the input  [1,5], [2,6], [7,10], [8,11] and [9,12]? Because my current answer does not consider that intersection should include all intervals meaning that there can be more than one intersections. Please let me know so that i can modify my answer.

Comment: @user2210078 Updated my answer to meet the requirements. Just included a max variable.

Comment: @user2210078 Thanks for the discussion. If you find a simpler algorithm, please inform me. Also I have updated my answer for better explanation.